# How to use has_secure_password with field_with_errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using has_secure_password to verify my user password and its confirmation. The problem I have is that when there are any errors, the fields are not being wrapped with a field_with_errors div. I know that I can add

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :on => :create
```

but that creates the following error message:

> Password digest can't be blank.
>   Password can't be blank.
>   Password confirmation can't be blank

I would like to **either** make the has_secure_password wrap the fields with errors with a field_with_errors div **or** remove the "Password digest can't be blank." error altogether.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [SecurePassword](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) module which has this functionality is quite simple and worth a look. Good news is that in [the master branch (Rails 4)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) it does `validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create` which will solve your problem, but in the meantime you might want to mimic the `has_secure_password` method on the User model yourself.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :password
  attr_accessible :password # ...
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, on: :create
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword::InstanceMethodsOnActivation
end
```

Also make sure `bcrypt` is loaded in Gemfile.

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0', require: 'bcrypt'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: worked great. i did have to add the `validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :on => :create` to wrap the confirmation field with a `<div class="field_with_errors">` thanks @ryanb

Answer (score 5):

As @ryanb stated, the `validates_presence_of :password` is fixed in master, but won't be backported. That fix also clears up the `Password digest can't be blank.` message.

So, in the model, you still need to add:

```
validates :password, presence: true, on: :create
```

As @henrique-zambon stated, there's no need to add a `validates_presence_of :password_confirmation`. To highlight the password confirmation field, without displaying that additional message, add an error on that field *after* you've displayed the errors.

Then, to hide the extra `Password digest can't be blank.` message, you can just remove it in the top of your form.

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    - @user.errors.delete(:password_digest)
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this user from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
    - @user.errors.add(:password_confirmation) if @user.errors.include?(:password)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to validate the presence of `:password_confirmation`, `has_secure_password` does that for you.

You may want to check this RailsCast: [Authentication in Rails 3.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1)

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of that but the `has_secure_password` doesn't wrap with the `field_with_errors` (but validating the presence of `:password_confirmation` does). Which is what I am trying to accomplish. any ideas?