# Why is password validate presence ignored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm following Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial. I'm stuck at section 6.3 with failing tests. The code should validate blank passwords, but if I create a User object with passwords, and then change the password field to blank, `valid?` returns true, which isn't expected according to the test spec.  Am I missing something?

I had to install the `protected_attributes` gem.  I prefer to use this gem to follow the tutorial code without modifications.

Running `bundle exec rspec spec` I get:

```
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:90 # User when password confirmation is nil 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:80 # User when password is not present
```

Here are my files.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

user_spec.rb (only the failing tests):

```
  describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

And here are a few tests I ran in the console:

```
max@top:~/prog/ruby/railstut$ rails c --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.0.0.rc1)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
irb(main):001:0> # Should return true.
irb(main):002:0* User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
irb(main):003:1*                      password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar").valid?
  User Exists (1.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('user@example.com') LIMIT 1
=> true
irb(main):004:0> 
irb(main):005:0* # Should return false.
irb(main):006:0* User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
irb(main):007:1*                      password: "", password_confirmation: "foobar").valid?
  User Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('user@example.com') LIMIT 1
=> false
irb(main):008:0> 
irb(main):009:0* # Oops. Expecting false.
irb(main):010:0* user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
irb(main):011:1*                      password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$ygkdtuJYF89ysbD86ZcO9ugiQZ0/FxOKvj87zEegJq.f...">
irb(main):012:0> 
irb(main):013:0* user.password = ""
=> ""
irb(main):014:0> 
irb(main):015:0* user.valid?
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('user@example.com') LIMIT 1
=> true
```

Comment: I never created a user model on my own before. If you are interested, take a look at [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). that's what most of the people are using

Comment: Shouldn't `validates :password_confirmation` be something like, `->{ |password_confirmation| password_confirmation == password }`?

Comment: Thanks Firyn. I'll check that when I'm done with the tutorial. =D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird issue in Rails 4, where for some reason you can't assign blank values to the password in that context. The code in the [Rails 4.0RC1 version of the tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0) and the [sample app](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4) have workarounds for Rails 4. Basically, you have to re-create the object using a hash, as in

```
describe "when password is not present" do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
  end
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

I've filed an [issue on the Rails GitHub repository](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10793) in the hopes of getting this problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `validates :password, presence: true` validation may conflict with the validations added by has_secure_password in Rails 4. See Ryan B's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905870/how-to-user-has-secure-password-with-field-with-errors)

Also, has_secure_password should already do `validates :password_confirmation, presence: true` for you, so you should remove that line from your model.